# Where are my changes saved when I execute "jspm registry create myregistry jspm-git"?

Tags: git, jspm

I have a repository on bitbucket that I want to manage with jspm but I always get timeouts on lookup where-as my coworker is successfully prompted for his username and pass.

I'm trying to locate my registry for jspm in order to debug - but am unable to do so and there doesn't seem to be any documentation on it.

The reason I'm trying to do this is because our steps include running "jspm registry create bitbucket jspm-git" but when I execute that command, from my previous run throughs it already exists. I want to make sure it's using the jspm-git package but I don't know how to check that either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been banging my head on this for hours and am likely going to start pursuing a different way of obtaining this level of management.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspm-git

https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli

Answer (score 1):

You can find the jspm registry config here:

```
~/.jspm/config
```

This is an JSON Object witch contains all the registries used by jspm, including the ones you created. But you need to add that custom registry first. You wont get it by jspm install. You have to add it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the "list of commands needed to recreate exactly that registry" via `jspm registry export name-of-your-registry` see: [docs on registries](https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/wiki/Registries#auto-configuring-registries)

Comment: The doc link in this answer is broken